# Can't configure a virtualenv TO NOT use packages outside my virtual environment on Windows

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have python 2.7 installed globally in `c:/python27` on Windows 7.

I successfully installed virtualenv 1.11.6 using `pip install virtualenv`

I then create a virtual env using `python.exe -m virtualenv c:/virtualenv/env1` and activate it:

> cd c:/virtualenv/env1/scripts
>
> activate

The prompt change showing we that everything worked properly:

`(env1) c:\virtualenv\env1\Scripts>`

Now my problem is that my just created virtual env is still inheriting packages from the global python27 and I don't want that.

I try creating a new virtual env using `--no-site-packages` but same problem.
In the [virtualenv documentation](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#the-system-site-packages-option) it is said that the `--system-site-packages` may be use to volontarily inherit packages from global python and that means that default behavior should be to not have that inheritance...

Any idea what is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Not sure it has anything to do with your issue, but where'd you find that usage?  I've never seen the usage of or used virtualenv as a python module, only as a script (virtualenv.exe from the Scripts directory, in a Windows install).  As a shot in the dark, maybe try using it that way instead.

Comment: I just create a new virtual env using C:/Python27/Scripts/virtualenv.exe c:/virtualenv/env1 like suggested but same issue

Comment: Can it be related to some mess in PYTHONPATH ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES ?

Comment: If you have your core install site-packages explicitly referenced in your PYTHONPATH, or if you've not actually installed anything in to the interpreter, but just dropped packages in to a directory on your PYTHONPATH, then yes.  But that would only be the case if you had set that up yourself.  If you installed with pip/easyinstall etc, and didn't mutilate your PYTHONPATH, everything should be contained to the site-packages of the specific interpreter instance.

Comment: My PYTHONPATH contains: c:\python27;c:\python27\lib;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python27\DLLs; I will try to remove it.

Comment: Cleaning my PYTHONPATH solve the problem... you can write the answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EtienneDesgagné, if you're cleaning it up manually, that's a workaround rather than a proper fix -- using virtualenv properly, it won't put site-packages in your PYTHONPATH to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the comment thread... solution is don't put your site-packages in your PYTHONPATH.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a new enough `virtualenv`, it won't include site-packages by default.

If you're using an older release, create it as follows:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages target-directory
```