# Should I delete all my python packages on computer

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

Ive just learned the importance of using a virtual library for projects using Python and Flask.  I have already downloaded some packages including flask-wtf, numPy and pandas.

If I have this installed on my computer outside of a virtual environment will it cause any issue when I run a program in my virtual environment?

Also, once something is installed to a virtual environment, is it saved on that virtual environment after the terminal is closed or the environment is deactivated?

Answer (score 1):

It will not cause any issue.

And the packages will be saved. The packages will still be there when you reactivate your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a virtual environment is to create an environment separate from whatever your base machine has installed. You can install old versions of Python libraries, etc. within a virtual environment without affecting your machine's base environment.

Therefore, when running your program in a virtual environment, there should be no problems as long as the correct versions of the libraries you need are installed within the virtual environment.

In regards to closing a virtual environment, all of the software installed in that environment persists. When you activate the virtual environment at a later time, it will be in the same state it was in when you deactivated it earlier.

I hope this answer clarifies some of your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

It is ideal that you remove global packages, until and unless it is absolutely required. However, it won't hamper the overall functioning of your machine, but will definitely occupy a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ virtualenv venv
```

creates a folder named venv and stores the virtual environment there.
Installed packages are stored in venv/lib/python?.?/site-packages and deactivating the environment and closing the terminal doesn't remove them.
You may remove the venv folder, in case you want for some reason to delete your virtual environment.

The packages you have installed globally (probably) won't affect your virtual environments. You (probably) can't use inside a virtual environment packages you have globally installed but not in the environment. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961748/my-virtual-environment-is-having-access-to-global-packages) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878699/cant-configure-a-virtualenv-to-not-use-packages-outside-my-virtual-environment), it seems to be possible, though.

About removing your globally installed packages, some time ago I got myself into some headache with trying to update my whole system after upgrading my globally installed Python packages with pip. Some of the packages that pip upgraded were dependencies for other packages and installed through distro's package manager and my package manager didn't like that. If this is not a problem for you, I don't know other downsides for having them installed globally other than the space.